# Using MSI to access Azure Key Vault in C# .Net

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-rbac

Since I am new to Azure, this question might be silly. I am trying to build a service to provision and manage a cluster of VMs. For security concerns, I don't want to put some sensitive data on each cluster. So I decide to provision an Azure Key vault for each cluster to store those data, and create a MSI(managed identity) and dispatch to each nodes of the cluster so that vm could access to the key vault to fetch the secrets.

On the service side, I need to provision vms, key vault and MSI. Assign the MSI to each VMs while grant the right role to MSI to access AKV. Here is my questions:

1. System MSI vs User MSI, since the cluster will have multiple nodes, to reduce the latency of provisioning the whole cluster, user msi probably a better idea since we could provision one MSI and grant the access one time. For system assigned MSI, we need to grant access for each identities. But the downside is, we have to delete the MSI when deleting the whole cluster. What your opinion on that?
2. Dumb question, how to provision a MSI, Azure Key vault and grant the access. Can you show me some code example? I tried to find the public API doc and tutorial online, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***1. What is the difference between a system-assigned and user-assigned managed identity?***

According to my research, A system-assigned managed identity is enabled directly on an Azure service instance.  The lifecycle of a system-assigned identity is directly tied to the Azure service instance that it's enabled on. If the instance is deleted, Azure automatically cleans up the credentials and the identity in Azure AD.

But, a user-assigned managed identity is created as a standalone Azure resource. After the identity is created, the identity can be assigned to one or more Azure service instances. The lifecycle of a user-assigned identity is managed separately from the lifecycle of the Azure service instances to which it's assigned.

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#how-does-the-managed-identities-for-azure-resources-work).

> ***2. How to provision a MSI, Azure Key vault and grant the access***

#### Provision a user-assigned managed identity

According to my research, if we want to provision a user-assigned managed identity, we can use the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-rest), [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-powershell) and [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-cli)

For example

Azure CLI

```
az login
az identity create -g <RESOURCE GROUP> -n <USER ASSIGNED IDENTITY NAME>
```

Azure REST API
a. Get access token with Azure CLI

```
az login
az account get-access-token
```

b. Call the rest api

```
curl 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroup
s/<RESOURCE GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<USER ASSIGNED IDENTITY NAME>?api-version=2015-08-31-preview' -X PUT -d '{"loc
ation": "<LOCATION>"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>"
```

#### Provision Azure Key vault and grant the access

According to my research, if we want to implement it,  we can if we want to provision a user-assigned managed identity, we can use the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults/createorupdate), [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/?view=azps-3.4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-1.2.0#key_vault), [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest) and sdk (such as .net). For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/)

For example

Azure Rest API

a. Get access token with Azure CLI

```
az login
az account get-access-token
```

b. Call the rest api

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{vaultName}?api-version=2018-02-14
Header :
   Content-Type: application/json
   Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>
Body

  {
  "location": "westus",
  "properties": {
    "tenantId": "<your tenant id>",
    "sku": {
      "family": "A",
      "name": "standard"
    },
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "tenantId": "<your tenant id>",
        "objectId": "<the object id of the MSI>",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "encrypt",
            "decrypt",
            "wrapKey",
            "unwrapKey",
            "sign",
            "verify",
            "get",
            "list",
            "create",
            "update",
            "import",
            "delete",
            "backup",
            "restore",
            "recover",
            "purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "get",
            "list",
            "set",
            "delete",
            "backup",
            "restore",
            "recover",
            "purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "get",
            "list",
            "delete",
            "create",
            "import",
            "update",
            "managecontacts",
            "getissuers",
            "listissuers",
            "setissuers",
            "deleteissuers",
            "manageissuers",
            "recover",
            "purge"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "enabledForDeployment": true,
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": true,
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true
  }
}
```

.Net SDK

a. [create a service principal with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role contributor --sdk-auth
```

b. Code. For more details, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-manage-key-vaults)

```
// please install package  Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
    .FromServicePrincipal(<the sp app id>,
    <the sp password>,
    tenantId, 
    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
    .Configure()
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithSubscription ("<your subscription id>");
var vault =await azure.Vaults.Define("")
                       .WithRegion(Region.AsiaSouthEast)
                       .WithExistingResourceGroup("groupname")
                       .DefineAccessPolicy()
                              .ForObjectId("the object id of msi")
                              .AllowCertificateAllPermissions()
                              .AllowKeyAllPermissions()
                              .AllowSecretAllPermissions()
                              .Attach()
                       .WithDeploymentEnabled()
                       .WithDiskEncryptionEnabled()
                       .WithTemplateDeploymentEnabled()
                       .WithSku(Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Fluent.Models.SkuName.Standard)
                       .CreateAsync()
```